# How to open a folder from memory card on a button click

Tags: android, android-button

I want to open the folder named as 'Songs' which is created in sd card on a button click.. please any body help me to do this

```
open.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
          {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "Songs");
           intent.setDataAndType(uri);
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open"));
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void Folder()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/Songs/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open"));
}
```